# onClick event is not triggering function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have the following script which attempts to change the color of a div, when clicked, with an id of wrapper.  I have tried variations of what's below, but can't see the issue.  The on click event does not trigger the function.

I have tried changing `background-color` to `backgroundColor`, which didn't make a difference.  I know I'm using a global variable here, please ignore that part:

```
var wrapper;

function wrapperColorToCoral () {
    wrapper.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:LightCoral;');
}

function wrapperColorToGreen () {
    wrapper.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:LightGreen;');
}

function colorChange () {
    //if (wrapper.getAttribute('style', 'background-color:LightCoral;') === true) {
    if (wrapper.style != 'background-color:LightGreen;') {
    wrapperColorToGreen();
    }
    else {
    wrapperColorToCoral();
    }
}
// INIT FUNCTION
function init () {
    wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
    wrapper.onClick = colorChange();
}

window.onload = init;
```

Edit (Working - Thanks Quentin):

```
var wrapper

function wrapperColorToCoral () {
    wrapper.style.backgroundColor="LightCoral";
}

function wrapperColorToGreen () {
    wrapper.style.backgroundColor="LightGreen";
}

function colorChange () {
    if (wrapper.style.backgroundColor==="LightCoral") {
    wrapperColorToGreen();
    }
    else {
    wrapperColorToCoral();
    }
}

function init () {
wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
wrapper.addEventListener("click", colorChange, false);
}
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: Change your init to: `wrapper.onclick = colorChange;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. JavaScript is case-sensitive. The property is `onclick` (but you should probably be using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) anyway).
2. Putting `()` on the end of a function name will call the function. You want to assign it to a property. Remove the parenthesis.

Comment: thanks so much! - so you recommend I do something more like:  `wrapper.addEventListener("click", colorChange, false);`?

Comment: @Quentin - could you tell me why it only listens once, but if I click a second time, it doesn't run the function again?

Comment: It does run the function again. `wrapper.style` doesn't give you the value you think it does.

Comment: @Quentin - still not getting it to work, I've made some edits above - when I do, `wrapper.style.backgroundColor="LightCoral";` in the console it works, but the function still doesn't seem to run again...

Comment: `=` is an *assignment*, not a comparison, it will always be `true`.

Comment: @Quentin - I should have known that - I really appreciate your help